# Time complexity of a tree related problem

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, time-complexity

I am struggling to figure out the time complexity of the following problem (this is not homework, just something I came up with and can't understand).

Suppose you have an arbitrary tree. The algorithm is such that for every node in the tree you have to run some O(1) operation as many times as that node's number of  leaf descendants. So, in the example tree below, we would run 2 operations for node A and 6 operations for the root node R.

[image: example tree]

Let's say you have n nodes, the tree is of depth d, and you may use any other notation necessary. What is the complexity?

I can't quite wrap my head around this. Surely it is less than O(n^2) but how do I approach this? Thank you!

Edit: leaf descendant of a node is a descendant that does not have any children. A descendant is a node reachable by repeated proceeding from parent to child (doesn't matter if it's an internal or a leaf node)

Comment: Isn't leaf descendants the number of all the nodes accessible from that leaf, so the descendants of ```R``` should be 9?

Comment: 9 descendants but 6 leaf descendants. So, a leaf is a node that does not have any children.

Comment: The link to the text is uncomfortable to read. Perhaps [upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Done! I couldn't do it by myself because I was lacking reputation, but nightfury1204 edited it for me, thanks!

Comment: I'm not very good at this stuff but here's my intuition. If you have n nodes, and each node has a corresponding number of leaf descendants d, then the complexity is nd. It's easy to see that d < n so nd < n^2. I don't think you can say anything else without specifying more information about the tree.

Comment: Interesting problem; I don't know the solution offhand but my suggestion for attacking it is to restrict the problem. Start with the simplest possible tree: the linked list. For a linked list, n = d, and clearly it is O(n). Now do a similar analysis for full binary trees, and so on, and see if a pattern emerges.  Good luck!

Comment: @billyb  Can you (the OP) provide the definition of the "leaf descendants" in the question to make it clear?

Comment: I think that the maximum number of O(1) operations is `(n - d + 1) * (d - 1)` with `1 < d <= n`. I don't have a rigorous proof, but if you try to maximize the number of leaves at the maximum depth, you will get this formula.

Comment: Do you execute anything for the non-leaf nodes under R? That is, the middle child of R has a descendant, and that descendant has 3 children. Would each of those non-leaf nodes execute 3 O(1) operations?

Comment: @JimMischel yes, this is correct. R's immediate middle child as well as that child's only child would each execute 3 operations. As for the 3 leaf nodes themselves, they would each execute one O(1) operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **Ө(n^2)**.  Obviously, as you noted, it's in **O(n^2)** because each node must have fewer than **n** descendant leaves.

In a tree with a construction like this:

```
     A
    /  \
   B    C
       / \
      D   E
         / \
        F   G
             ...
```

The top-most **n/4** internal nodes have at least **n/4** descendant leaves, so the total number of operations is at least **n^2/16**, which is in **Ω(n^2)**.

If you have a depth limit **d**, then each node can have at most **d** ancestors, so you get **O(n*min(d,n))**, which is also tight by a similar construction.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the n/4 top nodes/leaves part. Is number 4 arbitrary?

Comment: No.  In the constructed tree, n/2 of the nodes are leaves, and the other n/2 nodes are internal nodes.  The *top-most* n/4 internal nodes have n/4 leaf children, and the remaining n/2 nodes in the whole tree are in the right child of the last one.  Half of those, or n/4 nodes, are leaves.  Those leaves are *all* descendants of every one of the top-most n/4 internal nodes.

Comment: Also, if a node has at most d ancestors, it doesn't mean that it will have at most d leaf descendants, right? What am I missing here? (Sorry I am not good with complexity stuff, please bear with me)

Comment: That's right, but the number of (node,descendant) pairs, which is the total number of operations, is sum(ancestors of each leaf) AND sum(leaf descendents of each node) -- those come out to the same number.

Comment: The example tree shows that the OP is not talking about just binary tree.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu I'm constructing a worst case so I can make any kind of tree I like.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. You always have to account for the worst case scenario. P.S.: Give me some time to soak in all this discussion.

Comment: Are you sure? Even if you iterate over all nodes it is just ```O(N)```, how does iterating over descendants and perform ```O(1)``` operation be ```O(N ^ 2)```?

Comment: @JiaHaoXu I think you misunderstood the question.  The goal is not just to operate on each leaf.

Comment: @Matt Timmermans Even an ```O(1)``` operation has to be performed on each node, it will just be ```O(N)```.

Comment: @Matt Timmermans I'm making progress in understanding :D
I got your first comment. Re your second comment, I understand how the total number of operations is the number of (node, leaf descendant) pairs and that it is in fact equal to the two sums. But how exactly is that knowledge used in big-O?

Comment: As @EricLippert wrote, in case of a linked list, where n=d, the complexity is clearly O(n), so in general it is not true that it is O(n^2).

Comment: @LucaCremonesi it's a different problem if you impose an additional constraint.  If you want to measure the worst case complexity of the given problem, then you measure the worst case, not the best case.  Your comment on the question is correct, though -- for a specific depth rather than a depth limit, it's O(d(n-d))

Comment: @MattTimmermans - The OP asked: "Let's say you have n nodes, the tree is of depth d, and you may use any other notation necessary. What is the complexity?" Then the complexity is O(d(n-d)), not O(n^2).

Comment: @LucaCremonesi MattTimmermans gave the correct result for upper bounded `d` as well. I think your result is correct and tight for fully constraint `d` (assuming `n!=d`). However the question just wasn't very clear on how the depth is constraint.

Comment: @Matt Timmermans thank you so much for your answer and comments! I am marking your answer as correct because I understood why it is O(n^2) in the worst-case scenario that you gave. I would really appreciate it if you can address my previous comment about the relationship between total number of operations and variable d, if you have time. But in any case, thank you for sharing your knowledge, that really helped!

Comment: @eukaryota what do you mean by a fully constraint d? Just to clarify, I only introduced d because I felt like it could be involved in the complexity formula. Think of it as a property that any tree has. P.S. I still don't understand how we can use d to achieve a tighter bound.

Comment: @billyb With d being fully constraint, I mean that you consider only trees with fixed d (but d possibly dependent on n) for the worst-case analysis. For example if d is supposed to always be maximal, then there is only one tree with this property, the linear chain, for which the time complexity is `O(n)`, not `O(n^2)` because it has only one leaf. If however you allow tree with any d as input, then there are trees such that the wort time complexity is `O(n^2)` (in particular for `d` growing proportionally with n and proportionality factor strictly between 0 and 1).

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be `O(2(N - Leaf) + Leaf)` where `Leaf` is the number of descendants of the tree. `O(2(N - Leaf))` is required to iterate over the tree to find the leaf descendants and a `O(1)` operation needs to be performed on each of them.

Comment: As you were told in another comment, the operation per node is not `O(1)`, but `O(leaf descendants)`. Furthermore what would `descendants of the tree` be? Usually `descendants` is a property of a node. `O(2(...))` is identical to `O(...)` and would usually written in this shorter way and `2(N-Leaf)+Leaf` is just `2N-Leaf`.